# JFrame Image Collision Detection

Tags: java, image, jframe, collision-detection

So I have image that when the player collides with the sword image, the inventory image is changed to an inventory image containing the sword. I've looked all over to try to solve this problem! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class grow extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    int x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

    public grow() {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\map.jpg");
        Image i = ic.getImage();
        g2d.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);

        ImageIcon sw = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\sword.jpg");
        Image s = sw.getImage();
        g2d.drawImage(s, 100, 100, null);

        ImageIcon inv = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\inv.jpg");
        Image inv1 = inv.getImage();
        g2d.drawImage(inv1, 350, 0, null);

        ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\man.jpg");
        Image m = im.getImage();

        if(vely >= 0) {  
            g2d.drawImage(m, x, y, null);
        }
        if(vely < 0) {
            ImageIcon imb = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\manback.jpg");
            Image mb = imb.getImage();
            g2d.drawImage(mb, x, y, null);
        }
        if(velx > 0) {
            ImageIcon imr = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\manleft.jpg");
            Image mr = imr.getImage();
            g2d.drawImage(mr, x, y, null);
        }
        if(velx < 0) {
            ImageIcon iml = new         ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\manright.jpg");
            Image ml = iml.getImage();
            g2d.drawImage(ml, x, y, null);
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        x += velx;
        y += vely;

    }

    public void up() {
        vely = -2;
        velx = 0;
    }

    public void down() {
        vely = 2;
        velx = 0;
    }

    public void left() {
        vely = 0;
        velx = -2;
    }

    public void right() {
        vely = 0;
        velx = 2;
    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down();
        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        velx = 0;
        vely = 0;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            stop();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            stop();
        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            stop();
        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            stop(); 
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a proper game engine like libGDX or AndEngine. That will make stuff like this much simpler. Swing is not the best for game UIs.

Answer (score 0):

Create an invisible Rectangle object per ImageIcon.  I would recommend making each Object (ex. Man, Sword, etc) it's own class first.  Then do something like the following:

```
public class Man{

    private int x, y;
    private Image image;
    boolean visible;
    private int width, height;



    public Man(int x, int y) {

        ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\man.jpg");
        image = im.getImage();
        visible = true;
        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    //rest of your getters/setters

    //this will be used for collision detection
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }


    public void move() {
        //move code goes here
    }
}
```

You want to do this for the rest of your classes too.  Now let's assume you a Sword class as well.  Then you can detect collision as so:

```
    //create an instance of Man
    //create an instance of Sword


    Rectangle manRect = man.getBounds();
    Rectangle swordRect = sword.getBounds();


   if (manRect.intersects(swordRect )) {
       //perform your action code here
       //update sprites
   }
```

[Source](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/collision/)